# MAUI supporting Wear OS and Watch OS?

Tags: .net, xamarin, wear-os, watchos, maui

I'm thinking about to use MAUI, as soon it is released, for developing an app.
My app needs to run on iOS and Android. Next to the mobile app I will have an app for Wearables (watchOS and Wear OS). Xamarin is supporting all four need platforms. But for MAUI I only find the information that it will work for iOS and Android.
Does anybody know if it will also support watchOS and Wear OS?

Comment: There was a question about this on the Maui Github. Sadly it had no response. [Link](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions/1144)

Comment: @JuanSturla Thanks. I found that already on my research but because MAUI is supposed to be released next month, I hoped that someone has more information about that...

I was really happy when I found out that Xamarin is supporting watchOS and Wear OS and now it would be sad if "the new version" MAUI is going backwards and not supporting it anymore...

Comment: Sadly, .NET MAUI release was posponed to first quarter 2022. We are not sure if it's going to support it or not. I hope that it does!

Answer (score 3):

According to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/supported-platforms), As of now, there is no support for Wear OS/Watch OS for MAUI Framework.

> .NET Multi-platform App UI (.NET MAUI) apps can be written for the following platforms:
>
> - Android 5.0 (API 21) or higher.
> - iOS 10 or higher.
> - macOS 10.13 or higher (using Mac Catalyst).
> - Windows desktop and the Universal Windows Platform (UWP), using Windows UI Library (WinUI) 3.

You can raise a feature request from [HERE](https://twitter.com/Azure).

Answer (score 3):

Dear @SwethaKandikonda is right but newly with **Dotnet 8 `Preview`** and **Visual Studio Version 17.8.0 `Preview 5.0`** seems something is happening.
My hello world project works like a charm even I did not customized **AndroidManifest.xml**  file
Also discussed [here](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions/1144)
Please look at my project

[image]

Tip : you should `**not**` customize **AndroidManifest.xml** and it should be empty like this :
[image]

It should `**not**` have the `<Uses-SDK` line
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is support for Android WearOS applications: https://gist.github.com/vhugogarcia/4cacaa90b42495c21a62044efc298beb

You can find a working sample on a github issue as mentioned by the user ivictorhugo: https://twitter.com/ivictorhugo/status/1526561045698969604?s=20&t=JL5yBtfz4Zda9U_hHafKqw

Comment: watchOS "Unsupported"

Answer (score 0):

I am not acctually sure if there is no support for watch/wear OS.
Looking at the link vhugo wrote document says than there is no support for Android Auto and Apple Carplay but it is.
Links below:
Apple Carplay https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nNkVxegb2oU
So maybe there is support for watches as well

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!